# Saving of Google Apps script takes forever

Tags: google-apps-script

From around the 17 June 2012 the saving of the a script in a google apps spreadsheet has become unbearably slow - it used to take 5 seconds or less, now it takes around 2 minutes to save my script.

Whats up with that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should post this on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) as it is not a G. A. script question. ( btw,I didn't notice any problem with 'save')

Comment: If you raise this on the issue tracker, please be sure to let us know the approximate size of your projects (how many files, how many lines of code per file), and ideally the project key (from File > Project properties) as well.

Answer (score 0):

See [defect 1723](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1723) in the issue tracker.
I had the same issue with my code that was taking 5mn to save for approx 16 scripts averaging to 16,000 lines of code.

Seem the editor, or whatever process the code when we save do not like long uninterrupted lines of code. I had long lines representing range arrays with more of 4,600 characters in one line in the editor.
I cut the lines to smaller chunks, made sure I did not had any long lines of code or spacing.

Immediately my code was saving within 30s instead of 5mn.

So I strongly believe it's a bug Google have with the editor or code processing the save.